# Removing phrases in reverse order from a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists.

```
L1 = ['worry not', 'be happy', 'very good', 'not worry', 'good very', 'full stop'] # bigrams list
L2 = ['take into account', 'always be happy', 'stay safe friend', 'happy be always'] #trigrams list
```

If I look closely, L1 has  `'not worry'`  and `'good very'` which are exact reversed repetitions of `'worry not'` and `'very good'`.

I need to remove such reversed elements from the list. Similary in L2, `'happy be always'` is a reverse of `'always be happy'`, which is to be removed as well.

The final output I'm looking for is:

```
L1 = ['worry not', 'be happy', 'very good', 'full stop']
L2 = ['take into account', 'always be happy', 'stay safe friend']
```

I tried one solution

`[[max(zip(map(set, map(str.split, group)), group))[1]] for group in L1]`

But it is not giving the correct output.
Should I be writing different functions for bigrams and trigrams reverse repetition removal, or is there a pythonic way of doing this in a faster way,because I'll have to run this for about 10K+strings.

Comment: but how can you know which one is correct without analyses, so I mean how do you know `worry not` is correct or `not worry`

Comment: Any one of the occurance should be removed, whether or not it makes sense gramatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with list comprehensions if you iterate over the list from the end

```
lst = L1[::-1] # L2[::-1]
x = [s for i, s in enumerate(lst) if ' '.join(s.split()[::-1]) not in lst[i+1:]][::-1]

# L1: ['worry not', 'be happy', 'very good', 'full stop']
# L2: ['take into account', 'always be happy', 'stay safe friend']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an index set and add both direct and reversed n-grams to it:

```
index = set()
res = []

for x in L1:
    a = tuple(x.split())
    b = tuple(reversed(a))
    if a in index or b in index:
        continue
    index.add(a)
    index.add(b)
    res.append(x)

print(res)
```

Comment: Why check `b in index`?

Comment: Or alternatively: Why add `b` to `index`?

Answer (score 2):

Using a set of tuples is the way to deal with this:

```
L1 = ['worry not', 'be happy', 'very good', 'not worry', 'good very', 'full stop'] # bigrams list
L2 = ['take into account', 'always be happy', 'stay safe friend', 'happy be always'] #trigrams list

for list_ in L1, L2:
    s = set()
    for e in list_:
        t = tuple(e.split())
        if not t[::-1] in s:
            s.add(t)
    print([' '.join(e) for e in s])
```

**Output:**

```
['be happy', 'worry not', 'very good', 'full stop']
['always be happy', 'stay safe friend', 'take into account']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L1 = ['worry not', 'be happy', 'very good', 'not worry', 'good very', 'full stop'] # bigrams list
L2 = ['take into account', 'always be happy', 'stay safe friend', 'happy be always'] #trigrams list


def solution(lst):
    res = []
    for item in lst:
        if " ".join(item.split()[::-1]) not in res:
            res.append(item)
    return res

print(solution(L2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution (the complexity is linear with respect to the number of strings):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

d = defaultdict(list)
for s in L2:
    d[max(s, reversed(s.split()))].append(s)

result = list(map(itemgetter(0), d.values()))
```

Here are the results:

```
['worry not', 'be happy', 'very good', 'full stop']
['take into account', 'always be happy', 'stay safe friend']
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution consist on iterate foreach element in the list, transform that element in a list, sort it and compare with the next element making the same, transform it in a list and sort it, if the arrays are matching, remove this element.
Here is my code:

```
L1 = ['worry not', 'be happy', 'very good', 'not worry', 'good very', 'full stop'] # bigrams list
L2 = ['take into account', 'always be happy', 'stay safe friend', 'happy be always'] #trigrams l

def remove_duplicates(L):
    for idx_i, l_i in enumerate(L):
        aux_i = l_i.split()
        aux_i.sort()
        for idx_j, l_j in enumerate(L[idx_i+1:]):
            aux_j = l_j.split()
            aux_j.sort()
            if aux_i == aux_j:
                L.pop(idx_i + idx_j + 1)
    print(L)

remove_duplicates(L1)
remove_duplicates(L2)
```

The output is what you're looking for:

```
>>> remove_duplicates(L1)
['worry not', 'be happy', 'very good', 'full stop']
>>> remove_duplicates(L2)
['take into account', 'always be happy', 'stay safe friend']
```

Hope this works for you